# Printing the Header of a FITS file with astropy: NameError: name 'header' is not defined

Tags: python, header, astropy, fits

I am trying to learn to use FITS operations through astropy via http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/

I am following the directions on this website. 
They are:

> "To see the entire header as it appears in the FITS file (with the END card and padding stripped), simply enter the header object by itself, or `print(repr(header))`"

But when I type `header`, I get the following error :

```
NameError: name 'header' is not defined
```

I get the same error when I put `print(header)` or `print(repr(header))` commands.

My question is why is it that the "header" command did not work?

Am I supposed to define it somehow?

My code:

```
from astropy.io import fits
hdulist = fits.open('test1.fits')
hdulist.info()
header
```

I am using jupyter notebook via Canopy.

Comment: Not to be glib, but to use Astropy you'll have to learn at least a little Python. That said, reading those docs, it's confusing because the examples switch from using a variable named `prihdr`, but then make an aside about how to print headers by using a header in a variable named `header`, expecting the reader to infer that `header` is a variable referencing a generic header. If you're familiar with Python syntax this is fairly clear, but could be confusing for beginners and should be changed.

Comment: That said, try starting the Python interpreter and just entering `asdf`. If you try to use an undefined variable in Python a `NameError` is what you'll get. Python doesn't know what `header` means if you don't define it.

Comment: Yes the documentation is confusing, it should use `prihdr` instead of `header`.

Comment: big thanks, that makes more sense now, and I can even do `print(repr(hdulist[0].header))` without defining any variable, but by pointing to the location in brackets "[0]", because I only had one HDU and therefore only one header. But if I had more, then I could do "[1]", etc.

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out, and I apologize, @MariaStone, for the tone of my first comment.  I didn't intend it to be hostile but it definitely comes off as belittling in retrospect and I would hate to discourage new users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is why is it that the "header" command did not work?
>
> Am I supposed to define it somehow?

In short: It's not a command and you don't need to define it. It's actually an attribute, so you have to look it up on the `hdulist`.

The `hdulist` contains `hdu`s and each `hdu` contains a `data` and a `header`, so to access the header of the first hdu you use:

```
print(repr(hdulist[0].header))
```

The `[0]` is because I wanted the first HDU (python uses zero-based indexing) and the `.header` accesses the header attribute of this HDU.

Even though I said you don't *need* to define it, but you *can* define a variable called header:

```
header = hdulist[0].header   # define a variable named "header" storing the header of the first HDU
print(repr(header))  # now it's defined and you can print it.
```

How many HDUs are present should be shown by the `hdulist.info()`, so you can decide which one you want to print or store.

Note that you should always use `open` as a context manager so it closes the file automatically (even in case of Errors):

```
from astropy.io import fits

with fits.open('test1.fits') as hdulist:  # this is like the "hdulist = fits.open('test1.fits')"
     hdulist.info()
     for hdu in hdulist:
         print(repr(hdu.header))
# After leaving the "with" the file closes.
```

This example also shows how you can use a `for` loop to go over all HDUs in a `HDUList`.